# Unzipping and the * operator

Tags: python

The python docs gives this code as the reverse operation of zip:

```
>>> x2, y2 = zip(*zipped)
```

In particular

> zip() in conjunction with the * operator can be used to unzip a list.

Can someone explain to me how the * operator works in this case? As far as I understand, * is a binary operator and can be used for multiplication or shallow copy...neither of which seems to be the case here.

Comment: The linked duplicate explains the actually asked question, "how the * operator works". For the overall problem of how `zip` undoes itself, see [Why does x,y = zip(*zip(a,b)) work in Python?](/questions/2511300).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When used like this, the * (asterisk, also know in some circles as the "splat" operator) is a signal to unpack arguments from a list. See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists for a more complete definition with examples.

Answer (score 62):

Although [hammar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917522/unzipping-and-the-operator/5917600#5917600) explains how the reversing works in the case of the `zip()` function, it may be useful to look at argument unpacking in a more general sense. Let's say we have a simple function which takes some arguments:

```
>>> def do_something(arg1, arg2, arg3):
...     print 'arg1: %s' % arg1
...     print 'arg2: %s' % arg2
...     print 'arg3: %s' % arg3
... 
>>> do_something(1, 2, 3)
arg1: 1
arg2: 2
arg3: 3
```

Instead of directly specifying the arguments, we can create a list (or tuple for that matter) to hold them, and then tell Python to *unpack* that list and use its contents as the arguments to the function:

```
>>> arguments = [42, 'insert value here', 3.14]
>>> do_something(*arguments)
arg1: 42
arg2: insert value here
arg3: 3.14
```

This behaves as normal if you don't have enough arguments (or too many):

```
>>> arguments = [42, 'insert value here']
>>> do_something(*arguments)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/blair/<ipython console> in <module>()

TypeError: do_something() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

You can use the same construct when defining a function to accept any number of positional arguments. They are given to your function as a tuple:

```
>>> def show_args(*args):
...     for index, value in enumerate(args):
...         print 'Argument %d: %s' % (index, value)
...
>>> show_args(1, 2, 3)
Argument 0: 1
Argument 1: 2
Argument 2: 3
```

And of course you can combine the two techniques:

```
>>> show_args(*arguments)
Argument 0: 42
Argument 1: insert value here
```

You can do a similar thing with keyword arguments, using a double asterix (`**`) and a dictionary:

```
>>> def show_kwargs(**kwargs):
...     for arg, value in kwargs.items():
...         print '%s = %s' % (arg, value)
...
>>> show_kwargs(age=24, name='Blair')
age = 24
name = Blair
```

And, of course, you can pass keyword arguments through a dictionary:

```
>>> values = {'name': 'John', 'age': 17}
>>> show_kwargs(**values)
age = 17
name = John
```

It is perfectly acceptable to mix the two, and you can always have required arguments and optional extra arguments to a function:

```
>>> def mixed(required_arg, *args, **kwargs):
...     print 'Required: %s' % required_arg
...     if args:
...         print 'Extra positional arguments: %s' % str(args)
...     if kwargs:
...         print 'Extra keyword arguments: %s' % kwargs
...
>>> mixed(1)
Required: 1
>>> mixed(1, 2, 3)
Required: 1
Extra positional arguments: (2, 3)
>>> mixed(1, 2, 3, test=True)
Required: 1
Extra positional arguments: (2, 3)
Extra keyword arguments: {'test': True}
>>> args = (2, 3, 4)
>>> kwargs = {'test': True, 'func': min}
>>> mixed(*args, **kwargs)
Required: 2
Extra positional arguments: (3, 4)
Extra keyword arguments: {'test': True, 'func': <built-in function min>}
```

If you are taking optional keyword arguments and you want to have default values, remember you are dealing with a dictionary and hence you can use its `get()` method with a default value to use if the key does not exist:

```
>>> def take_keywords(**kwargs):
...     print 'Test mode: %s' % kwargs.get('test', False)
...     print 'Combining function: %s' % kwargs.get('func', all)
... 
>>> take_keywords()
Test mode: False
Combining function: <built-in function all>
>>> take_keywords(func=any)
Test mode: False
Combining function: <built-in function any>
```

Answer (score 25):

`zip(*zipped)` means "feed each element of `zipped` as an argument to `zip`". `zip` is similar to transposing a matrix in that doing it again will leave you back where you started.

```
>>> a = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
>>> b = zip(*a)
>>> b
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
>>> zip(*b)
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
```

Answer (score 6):

That's actually pretty simple once you really understand what `zip()` does.

The `zip` function takes several arguments (all of iterable type) and pair items from these iterables according to their respective positions.

For example, say we have two arguments `ranked_athletes, rewards` passed to `zip`, the function call `zip(ranked_athletes, rewards`) will:

- pair athlete that ranked first (position i=0) with the first/best reward (position i=0)
- it will move the the next element, i=1
- pair the 2nd athlete with its reward, the 2nd from `reward`.
- ...

This will be repeated until there is either no more athlete or reward left. For example if we take the 100m at the 2016 olympics and `zip` the rewards we have:

```py
ranked_athletes = ["Usain Bolt", "Justin Gatlin", "Andre De Grasse", "Yohan Blake"]
rewards = ["Gold medal", "Silver medal", "Bronze medal"]
zip(ranked_athletes, rewards)
```

Will return an iterator over the following tuples (pairs):

```
('Usain Bolt', 'Gold medal')
('Justin Gatlin', 'Silver medal')
('Andre De Grasse', 'Bronze medal')
```

Notice how *Yohan Blake* has no reward (because there are no more reward left in the `rewards` list).

[image]

The `*` operator allows to *unpack* a list, for example the list `[1, 2]` unpacks to `1, 2`. It basically transform one object into many (as many as the size of the list). You can read more about this operator(s) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2921893/1720199).

So if we combine these two, `zip(*x)` actually means: ***take this list of objects, unpack it to many objects and pair items from all these objects according to their indexes***. It only make sense if the objects are iterable (like lists for example) otherwise the notion of *index* doesn't really make sense.

Here is what it looks like if you do it step by step:

```py
>>> print(x)              # x is a list of lists 
[[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]

>>> print(*x)             # unpack x
[1, 2, 3]  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

>>> print(list(zip(*x)))  # And pair items from the resulting lists
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

Note that in this case, if we call `print(list(zip(x)))` we will just pair items from `x` (which are 2 lists) with nothing (as there are no other iterable to pair them with):

```
[  ([1, 2, 3],    ),  (['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],    )]
               ^                              ^
    [1, 2, 3] is paired with nothing          |
                                              |
                        same for the 2nd item from x: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Another good way to understand how `zip` works is by implementing your own version, here is something that will do more or less the same job as `zip` but limited to the case of two lists (instead of many iterables):

```py
def zip_two_lists(A, B):
    shortest_list_size = min(len(A), len(B))
    # We create empty pairs
    pairs = [tuple() for _ in range(shortest_list_size)]
    # And fill them with items from each iterable 
    # according to their the items index:
    for index in range(shortest_list_size):
        pairs[index] = (A[index], B[index])
    return pairs

print(zip_two_lists(*x))
# Outputs: [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

Notice how I didn't call `print(list(zip_two_lists(*x)))` that's because this function unlike the real `zip` isn't a generator (a function that constructs an iterator), but instead we create a list in memory. Therefore this function is not as good, you can find a better [approximation to the real `zip` in Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#zip). It's often a good idea to read these code equivalences you have all around this documentation, it's a good way to understand what a function does without any ambiguity.

Answer (score -1):

I propose this one to unzip a zipped list of lists when zip is done with izip_longest:

```
>>> a =[2,3,4,5,6]
>>> b = [5,4,3,2]
>>> c=[1,0]]

>>>[list([val for val in k if val != None]) for k in 
                                       zip(*itertools.izip_longest(a,b,c))]
```

as izip_longest is appending None for lists shortest than the longest, I remove None beforehand. And I am back to the original a,b,c

```
[[2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [5, 4, 3, 2], [1, 0]]
```