# Python iterate through lists within tuple data structure

Tags: python

I have the following data structure:

```
data = (['test1','test2','test3'], ['foo1','foo2','foo3'], ['bar1','bar2','bar3'])
```

I want to iterate through this data structure and create a new tuple which appends position 1 of each list to it. I would like to create a data structure with

```
(test1,foo1,bar1), (test2,foo2,bar2), (test3,foo3,bar3)
```

Comment: These are not valid data structures, you are missing commas.

Comment: easy peasy, this will be answered in a zip

Comment: I just wrote it to outline what it looks like...My apologies

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matrix Transpose in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937491/matrix-transpose-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

This is an easy [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip) with [argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
print zip(*data)
```

e.g.:

```
>>> data = (['test1','test2','test3'],['foo1','foo2','foo3'],['bar1','bar2','bar3'])
>>> zip(*data)
[('test1', 'foo1', 'bar1'), ('test2', 'foo2', 'bar2'), ('test3', 'foo3', 'bar3')]
```

Answer (score 3):

Unzip it via [zip()](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> data = (['test1','test2','test3'],['foo1','foo2','foo3'],['bar1','bar2','bar3'])
>>> zip(*data)
[('test1', 'foo1', 'bar1'), ('test2', 'foo2', 'bar2'), ('test3', 'foo3', 'bar3')]
```

Also see: [Unzipping and the * operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917522/unzipping-and-the-operator).