# Basic CSV x-y Plotting with Python

Tags: python, csv, plot

Trying to write a python script that reads a csv file and prints an x-y plot.  I have a csv file with a few rows and columns worth of data. I'd like to plot an x-y plot for the first and second column. Here is what I've got so far...

```
import csv
def getColumn(filename, column):
    results = csv.reader(open(filename), delimiter="\t")
    return [result[column] for result in results]

x = getColumn("TableOne.csv",0)
y = getColumn("TableOne.csv",1)

plt.figure("X-Y Plot")
plt.xlabel("Site")
plt.ylabel("Average")
plt.plot(x,y)
```

... but it's reading my csv file by row, not column, which outputs a bunch of mixed data instead of the one specific data I want.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide few lines of the TableOne.csv? Do head -5 TableOne.csv

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function and some answers regarding [zip splats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917522/unzipping-and-the-operator).

You can easily do this with:

```
In [1]: data = [['x1', 'y1'], ['x2', 'y2'], ['x3', 'y3']]

In [2]: zip(*data)
Out[2]: [('x1', 'x2', 'x3'), ('y1', 'y2', 'y3')]
```

Here, the `*data` unpacks `data` into 3 lists of `[x, y]` pairs.  Then `zip` packages these together by taking the first element of each list into one group, the second element of each list into another group, and so on.  Since you only have 2 elements per list, `zip(*data)` returns two groups, the x and y elements separately.

In your case, change

```
def getColumns(filename):
    results = csv.reader(open(filename), delimiter="\t")
    return zip(*list(results)) # may not need the list() but just in case

x, y  = getColumns("TableOne.csv")

plt.figure("X-Y Plot")
plt.xlabel("Site")
plt.ylabel("Average")
plt.plot(x,y)
```