# fetching certain elements in a list in python

Tags: python, list

I am new to Python. Imagine we have a list like this:
[(1,0.2), (2,4.8), (5,5.6)]
I want to fetch the all left side elements so that I have a list like this:
[1,2,5]
I am wondering how I can do that. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: `[i[0] for i in lst]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension statement like:

```
example = [(1,0.2), (2,4.8), (5,5.6)]
[x[0] for x in example]
```

which basically iterates through all your elements, and grabs the first element in each tuple, and creates a new array out of it.

Answer (score 2):

```
m =  [(1,0.2), (2,4.8), (5,5.6)] 

out_list = []
for element in m:
    out_list.append(element[0])
print out_list
```

You have to navigate thru all the `elements` of `m` , then, take the first number with `element[0]` and append it to a new list titled `out_list`

The code will output

```
[1,2,5]
```

You can you this on a more ellegant way using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) as follows:

```
out_list = [element[0] for element in m ] 
print out_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Most people suggest list comprehension as the solution to your problem, which is great. But python can do the same thing via different approaches. Recently I learnt how to "unzip" a list and the technique fits right into your problem.

```
zipped = [(1,0.2), (2,4.8), (5,5.6)]
list(zip(*zipped)[0])
```

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917522/unzipping-and-the-operator) thread, people explained how it works. Hope you will get something from it. Welcome to the python world!