# Save a dict with lists as csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I've dictionary in this format:

```
d = {'key_1':['item_1','item_2','item_3'],'key_2':['item_1','item_2','item_3'],}
```

And I need to save it in csv format.

I did this:

```
import csv

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f: 
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, d.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(d)
```

But I get only one row for the header and one more row for the items, I want each item in a different row  as what you get with pandas.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

But of course in this case without using pandas.

Comment: What exactly is your desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This program does what you want, assuming that `len(d['key_1']) == len(d['key_2'])`.

```
import csv

d = {
    'key_1':['item_1','item_2','item_3'],
    'key_2':['2_item_1','2_item_2','2_item_3'],
}

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(d.keys())
    w.writerows(zip(*d.values()))
```

Result:

```
key_1,key_2
item_1,2_item_1
item_2,2_item_2
item_3,2_item_3
```

If the value lists might be of varying length, try this:

```
import csv
import itertools

d = {
    'key_1':['item_1','item_2','item_3'],
    'key_2':['2_item_1','2_item_2','2_item_3', '2_item_4'],
}

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(d.keys())
    w.writerows(itertools.izip_longest(*d.values()))
```

Result:

```
key_1,key_2
item_1,2_item_1
item_2,2_item_2
item_3,2_item_3
,2_item_4
```

Comment: what  it does the '*' in itertools.izip_longest(*d.values()) ?

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917522/unzipping-and-the-operator http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-python https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/35395-voodoo-zip-somelist