# Python: TypeError: argument after * must be a sequence

Tags: python, multithreading, typeerror

I have this piece of code in which I try to send an UDP datagram in a new thread

```
import threading, socket

address = ("localhost", 9999)


def send(sock):
    sock.sendto("Message", address)
    print "sent"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
threading.Thread(target=send, args=(s)).start()
```

But when I try to give the socket as an argument to the function, a TypeError exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in 
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
TypeError: send() argument after * must be a sequence, not _socketobject
```

What that means?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to add a comma - `,` - after your variable `s`. Sending just s to args=() is trying to unpack a number of arguments instead of sending just that single arguement.

So you'd have `threading.Thread(target=send, args=(s,)).start()`

Also the splat - `*` - operator might be useful in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917522/unzipping-and-the-operator) question explaining it's usage and unzipping arguments in general