# Making a TCP Chatroom and getting error in threading

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

Making a TCP Chatroom using socket and thread but getting error in threading.
Client is local client and another client using another device. 
Error occurred on server log

There is handle function in server side which is giving error that there should be iterable not socket so how could I solve it.
Server Side:

```
# Sending Messages To All Connected Clients
def broadcast(message):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(message)

# Handling Messages From Clients
def handle(client):
    while True:
        try:
            # Broadcasting Messages
            message = client.recv(1024)
            broadcast(message)
        except:
            # Removing And Closing Clients
            index = clients.index(client)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
            nickname = nicknames[index]
            broadcast('{} left!'.format(nickname).encode('ascii'))
            nicknames.remove(nickname)
            break

# Receiving / Listening Function
def receive():
    while True:
        # Accept Connection
        client, address = server.accept()
        print("Connected with {}".format(str(address)))

        # Request And Store Nickname
        client.send('NICK_NAME'.encode('ascii'))
        nickname = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
        nicknames.append(nickname)
        clients.append(client)

        # Print And Broadcast Nickname
        print("Nickname is {}".format(nickname))
        broadcast("{} joined!".format(nickname).encode('ascii'))
        client.send('Connected to server!'.encode('ascii'))

        # Start Handling Thread For Client
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client))
        thread.start()

receive()
input('Press Enter to Close the Server.')
```

Client Side:

```
# Listening to Server and Sending Nickname
def receive():
    while True:
        try:
            # Receive Message From Server
            # If 'NICK_NAME' Send Nickname
            message = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
            if message == 'NICK_NAME':
                client.send(nickname.encode('ascii'))
            else:
                print(message)
        except:
            # Close Connection When Error
            print("An error occured!")
            client.close()
            break

# Sending Messages To Server
def write():
    while True:
        message = '{}: {}'.format(nickname, input(''))
        client.send(message.encode('ascii'))

# Starting Threads For Listening And Writing
receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive)
receive_thread.start()

write_thread = threading.Thread(target=write)
write_thread.start()
```

Getting following error when connecting to server on server side:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anil soni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Anil soni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: handle() argument after * must be an iterable, not socket
```

Using python 3.8.5 and VS Code 
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387596/python-typeerror-argument-after-must-be-a-sequence, This might help!

Comment: Am on my phone so cannot test but try `thread = threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client,))`. Note comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `,` in the args worked!!!

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client,))
```

Comment: Thanks but how would you solved the error why we need to add ```,```

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#when-to-use-trailing-commas. This will clearly explain to you.