# dynamic format the string from tuples of tuple using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

In the below, Scenario 1 is working fine in both (Code 1 & Code 2). But Scenario 2 is not working in Code 1.

My requirement is Tuple should keep on repeating itself until it fills all the formatting string in the Query dynamically. Because where clauses are not constant for all the queries.

**Scenario 1#**

```
query = SELECT * FROM test.order where total_price in {}
```

Tuple:

```
finTup=((125, 125, 125, 125),)
SELECT * FROM test.order where total_price in (125, 125, 125, 125)
```

**Scenario 2#**

```
query = SELECT * FROM test.order WHERE order_id IN {} AND product_id IN {}
```

Tuple:

```
finTup=((101, 105, 106, 107), (2, 2, 2, 2))
```

**Code 1:**

```
frt = 'finTup[{}]'
half = ''
val = ''
i = 0
le = len(finTup)
for i in range(le):
    print(i)
    print(eval(frt.format(i)))
    if i == le -1:
        half = half + frt.format(i)
        val = val + " " + frt.format(i)
    else:
        half = half + frt.format(i)+', '
        val = val + " " + frt.format(i)+', '
temp2 = query.format(eval(val))
```

**Code 2:**

```
if le == 1:
     query = query.format(finTup[0])
elif le == 2:
      query = query.format(finTup[0], finTup[1])
 elif le == 3:
       query = query.format(finTup[0], finTup[1], finTup[2])
elif le == 4:
       query = query.format(finTup[0], finTup[1], finTup[2], finTup[3])

Error:
temp2 = query.format(eval(val))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Code 2 is a static one, which I need to replace with dynamic code.

Comment: Give a suitable input and output

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

Hello, you have this error because you are trying to provide a single argument to the `format` function which expects two parameters (since you have 2 `{}`).

**Note**: Avoid using the `eval` function... That's pretty not recommended, even less in the current situation that you are. Everything can be done without having to evaluate a `str`.

---

In what follows, I only run the code for **Scenario #2**, i.e.

```py
query2 = """SELECT * FROM test.order WHERE order_id IN {} AND product_id IN {}"""
finTup = ((101, 105, 106, 107), (2, 2, 2, 2))
```

---

### Step 1: Debugging

Let's imagine you update your code for debugging as follows:

```py
frt = 'finTup[{}]'
half = ''
val = ''
i = 0 # btw, you don't need to initialize i here
le = len(finTup)

for i in range(le):
    if i == le -1:
        half = half + frt.format(i)
        val = val + " " + frt.format(i)
    else:
        half = half + frt.format(i)+', '
        val = val + " " + frt.format(i)+', '

print val
print eval(val)

temp2 = query.format(eval(val))
```

Your output should be:

```
 vars[0],  vars[1]
((101, 105, 106, 107), (2, 2, 2, 2))
```

So, imagine you write python code from the above output, what you would do is:

```py
query.format(((101, 105, 106, 107), (2, 2, 2, 2)))
```

You are actually providing a single parameter of type `tuple` with a two elements. But what's important here is that you provide `format` with **a single parameter**.  The `format` function will try to access the second parameter, which you don't provide. It breaks.

---

### Step 2: Fixing the code

Have a look at this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917522/unzipping-and-the-operator). It shows you how to use the `*` operator. It basically transforms a `list` or `tuple` into a sequence of items. Perfect for functions parameters and so forth.

So, applied to your current case:

```py
temp2 = query.format(*eval(val))
```

And the trick is done.

---

### Step 3: Optimization

Now, let's trash the **Code 1** and use what we've learn with **Code 2**. We need to unpack the `tuple` of `tuple` into parameters to feed in to `format`. So, why not *just* do:

```py
# I renamed `finTup` to `vars` since I don't know what it means
def get_query(query, vars):
    return query.format(*vars)
```

It basically combines the logic of **Code 1** and **Code 2** into a single line.