# Print Value from Key and Value in one list in a new empty list based on matching elements

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

**Logic Behind Problem:**
When building a route you need two steps in order to perform a direction. For example if you go from Step1 to Step2 that is right. But Step1 to Step3 is left. The steps need to be in pairs in order to determine direction.

**Issue:**
I have a function that produces a `'Direction'` based on a pair of elements in `'StepName'`. If a routes `'StepName'` pair is already defined with `'Direction'` it should be able to produce the same `'Direction'` in another route dictionary if it contains the same pair of elements in a sequence of pairs. Doesn't matter at what index the pair is located in the list

**For example:**

- `104-1 to 104-2` produces `'Left'` in `'Direction'`
- `104-2 to 105-A` produces `'Right'` in `'Direction'`
- `105-A to 105-D` produces `'Right'` in `'Direction'`

**Code:**

```
route1 = {
    'RouteID': 1,
    'StepID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'StepName': ['104-1', '104-2', '105-A', '105-D'],
    'Direction': ['Left', 'Right', 'Right']}

route2 = {
    'RouteID': 2,
    'StepID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'StepName': ['104-2', '105-A', '105-C', '105-B'],
    'Direction': []}

def routeMapper(longRoute, subRoute):
    for i, v in enumerate(subRoute['StepName']):
        found = False
        for j, b in enumerate(longRoute['StepName']):
            if v == b:
                found = True
                subRoute['Direction'].append(longRoute['Direction'][j])
        if not found:
            subRoute['Direction'].append(False)

routeMapper(route1, route2)
print(route2)
```

**Output:**

```
{'RouteID': 2, 'StepID': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'StepName': ['104-2', '105-A', '105-C', '105-B'], 'Direction': ['Right', 'Right', False, False]}
```

As you can see it is comparing what each index element direction it is assigned to. I want it to be seen in pairs instead of single.

**Desired Output: (for 'Direction')**

```
{'RouteID': 2, 'StepID': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'StepName': ['104-2', '105-A', '105-C', '105-B'], 'Direction': ['Right', False, False, False]}
```

The reason this output makes sense is because in `route1` `104-2 to 105-A` produces `'Right'` even though it is `1` and `2` in the index as a pair compared to it being at the `0` and `1` index in `route2`. As long as the pair is found in the list it should be able to produce the direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first created a list named `pair1` that will keep hold of `i` & `i+1` elements from the `subRoute`'s `StepName` in the first loop. I've also done the same to the `longRoute` in the second loop. Then if the first element of each pair ***and*** both of the pairs match, the function will append the `direction` of that pair's. If not, it will append `False`.  (I had to restructure the loops to make this work)

```py
def routeMapper(longRoute, subRoute):
    for i in range(len(subRoute['StepName']) - 1):
        found = False
        pair1 = [subRoute['StepName'][i], subRoute['StepName'][i+1]]
        for j in range(len(longRoute['StepName']) - 1):
            pair2 = [longRoute['StepName'][j], longRoute['StepName'][j+1]]
            if pair1[0]==pair2[0] and pair1 == pair2:
                found = True
                subRoute['Direction'].append(longRoute['Direction'][j])
        if not found:
                subRoute['Direction'].append(False)

    #Output: {'RouteID': 2, 'StepID': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'StepName': ['104-2', '105-A', '105-C', '105-B'], 'Direction': ['Right', False, False]}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to:

- create a dictionary mapping location pairs (`104-1` to `104-2`) to their respective directions (`Left`): function `route_directions`
- then, using this dictionary we could compute the second route directions quite easily: function `derive_directions`

```
def route_directions(route):
    directions = route['Direction']
    steps = route_steps(route)
    return {step:direction for step, direction in zip(steps, directions)}

# Utility function (we could also use itertools.pairwise instead of this)
def route_steps(route):
    return zip(route['StepName'], route['StepName'][1:])

def derive_directions(route, existing_directions):
    return [existing_directions.get(step, False) for step in route_steps(route)]
```

Using all these functions, we can simply derive `route2` directions from  `route1`:

```
route_directions = route_dict(route1)
route2['Direction'] = derive_directions(route2, route_directions)
```

#### Few things used here

- [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) that I also tried to describe a bit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917522/unzipping-and-the-operator/55499582#55499582). Basically it match two (or more) list element-wise, for example, `zip([1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30])`, will produce the following tuples `(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30)`.
- This code also uses the fact that tuples can be used as dictionary keys, here is what the `route_directions` looks like:

```
{('104-1', '104-2'): 'Left',
 ('104-2', '105-A'): 'Right',
 ('105-A', '105-D'): 'Right'}
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative solution and detailed explanation!