# generating a series of numbers without using any string functions in python

Tags: python

I'm new to python programming and solving some problems in Hacker Rank..
the question was to read an interget N and print in the format of 123....N without using any string methods.
I did the following

```
Answer = ''

for i in range(1,Input+1):
    Answer += str(i)

print Answer
```

When i looked into the other solution one of the solution given was

```
print(*range(1,N+1), sep='')
```

I tried to understand this but could not. I could not find any documentation for *range. can someone pls help..

Comment: Google unpacking in python.

Comment: The `*` is for unpacking lists: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2511332/7517724

Comment: Also, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480184/unpack-a-list-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given expression is calling the [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) built-in function, plus the [unpacking arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments) operator `*` (a.k.a. the "splat" operator), that simply expands a sequence into its individual elements. For example:

```
print(*range(1, 5+1), sep='')
```

Will expand to this:

```
print(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, sep='')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can store the iteration results in a list and remove the comma and print it :

```
res = ()
for i in range(1,n+1):
    res+=(i,)
    fin = ''.join(map(str,res))
print(fin)
```