# getting error while submiting in dynamic form in django

Tags: python, django-forms

I'm trying to create dynamic form with corresponding fields using
following code. But getting problem while submiting value.

If i entered blank value then error is :

```
Attribute Error:
'module' object has no attribute ''
```

in forms.py,
and if I entered value for salary then error is:

```
Attribute Error:
'module' object has no attribute '100000'
```

in forms.py

Here is forms.py

```
from django import forms

class ContextForm(forms.Form):

         def __init__(self. rdict, *args, **kwargs):
               super(ContextForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
               for key in rdict.keys():
                     self.fields['%s' % str(key)] = getattr(forms,rdict.get(key))()



rdict = {'address': 'CharField','phone': 'CharField', 'Salary': 'IntegerField','first name': 'CharField','last name':'CharField'}

c = ContextForm(rdict)
```

Comment: Which line is raising tha `AttributeError`? Where's the point where you use `'100000'`?

Comment: getting error on "self.fields['%s' % str(key)] = getattr(forms,rdict.get(key))()" this line

Comment: and rdict is dict which i m passing through view

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your view code looks like this:

```
c = ContextForm(request.POST, rdict)
```

If you replace it with:

```
 c = ContextForm(rdict, request.POST)
```

it works just fine.
For explanation read [Python normal arguments vs. keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419046/python-normal-arguments-vs-keyword-arguments).

Comment: i've tried c = ContextForm(rdict, request.POST) but its not working.

Comment: as you said c = ContextForm(rdict, request.POST) is working properly. It was my mistake i was trying something else. **thank you**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is an error in your forms.py:

```
$ python forms.py
  File "forms.py", line 5
    def __init__(self. rdict, *args, **kwargs):
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Then, I believe the problem is the following. Maybe, you're trying to create the form with the code like this:

```
new_form = ContextForm(request.POST, something_else)
```

Therefore, if your `request.POST` is something like this:

```
{'some_field': '100000'}
```

Then in this line:

```
self.fields['%s' % str(key)] = getattr(forms,rdict.get(key))()
```

`forms` is a module object, `key` is `'some_field'`, so `rdict.get(key)` is `'100000'` and

```
getattr(forms,rdict.get(key))()
```

is equivalent to:

```
getattr(forms, '100000')()
```

which is definitely not OK.

Comment: yes sir, its coming something like u said and i want this should be appear getattr(forms, 'XXXField'). How could i get this?

Comment: does `ContextForm(rdict, request.POST, anything_else_you_normally_pass_to_a_form_constructor)` help?

Comment: no,passing only dictionary. if request.method=='POST': 
  form = ContextForm(request.POST,rdict)

Comment: why do you pass `rdict` as second argument? according to `ContextForm` definition it must be first argument.

Comment: **thank you** for your co-ordination. As u said i've tried with rdict as 1st argument and now its working properly. Its creating dynamic form as well as its cheking for their field types