# What do * and ** before a variable name mean in a function signature?

Tags: python

What do the `*` and `**` mean in this code?

```
def functionA(self, *a, **kw):
   # code here
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments

Answer (score 310, accepted):

Inside a **function header**:

`*` collects all the positional arguments in a tuple.

`**` collects all the keyword arguments in a dictionary.

```
>>> def functionA(*a, **kw):
       print(a)
       print(kw)


>>> functionA(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, a=2, b=3, c=5)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
{'a': 2, 'c': 5, 'b': 3}
```

In a **function call**:

`*` unpacks a list or tuple into position arguments.

`**` unpacks a dictionary into keyword arguments.

```
>>> lis=[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> dic={'a': 10, 'b':20}
>>> functionA(*lis, **dic)  #it is similar to functionA(1, 2, 3, 4, a=10, b=20)
(1, 2, 3, 4)
{'a': 10, 'b': 20}
```

Comment: Interesting functionality, clearly explained.. Can understand the code now, might one day find a use for it in my own code. For a clear explanation of positional vs keyword arguments see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1419160/4288043)

Answer (score 13):

`**` takes specified argument names and puts them into a dictionary. So:

```
def func(**stuff):
    print(stuff)

func(one = 1, two = 2)
```

Would print:

```
{'one': 1, 'two': 2}
```

Answer (score 12):

`**` means named arguments of the functions.

```
$ cat 2.py
def k(**argv):
    print argv

k(a=10, b = 20)

$ python 2.py
{'a': 10, 'b': 20}
```

`argv` is a dictionary that contains all named arguments of the function.

And you can also reverse it. You can use a dictionary as a set of aruments
for a function:

```
def k(a=10, b=20):
  print a
  print b

d={'a':30,'b':40}
k(**d)
```

would print

```
30
40
```