# How to use the values of a list that is inside another list as arguments of a function in Python

Tags: python, list, function, arguments

I am very new to Python.  I have a function `DISTANCE(lat1, long1, lat2, long2)` that calculates the distance between 2 points.

Then I have a list called `POINTS`, where each value is another list which contains those four values.

I would like to obtain the sum of the results of the function `DISTANCE` for all the values inside `POINTS`.

Can anybody help me with that?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `for-in` loop if you're new to python:

```
result=[]
for item in POINTS:
    res=DISTANCE(*item)  
    result.append(res)
print(sum(result))
```

if you're confused about what's `*` here, you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11315061/846892)

Answer (score 8):

```
sum(DISTANCE(*p) for p in POINTS)
```

The `*` here is the syntax for [Unpacking Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), also called the splat operator.  This passes the contents of an iterable as the positional arguments to a function, so if `p` were `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, `DISTANCE(*p)` would be the same as `DISTANCE(1, 2, 3, 4)`.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
totalDistance = sum(DISTANCE(lat1, long1, lat2, long2) for (lat1, long1, lat2, long2) in POINTS)
```

Comment: You can drop the brackets `[]` and use a genexp instead of a listcomp.

Answer (score 4):

```
sum([DISTANCE(*args) for args in POINTS])
```

What this one-liner does is use a list comprehension on `POINTS`, applying each item in it as a list to `DISTANCE`, like this:

```
args = [1, 2, 3, 4]
DISTANCE(*args) == DISTANCE(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

The call to `sum` takes a list itself and returns the sum of all the items within.

A side suggestion: name your functions in all lowercase.  [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) has a lot of good style suggestions for making readable Python code.