# variable positional and printing the values

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, function-call

```
def minimum (*n):
        print(n)
minimum(1)
minimum(1,2)
    
    
def func(*args):
     print(args)
    
values1 = (1,2)
values2 = ((1,2), (3,4))
func(values1)
func(values2)

OUTPUT:
(1,)
(1, 2)
((1, 2),)
(((1, 2), (3, 4)),)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

First O/p:
I think python is expecting multiple arguments to be passed so there is a comma (,) after 1. ?

Second O/p:
Now the python sees multiple arguments being passed there is no comma. It stores the args a tuple?

Third O/p and Fourth O/p:
Why is there still a comma? even after I passed 2 tuples assuming that python is expecting multiple tuples like the above?

Help me understand this.

Comment: `func(val)` passes exactly one argument. Which ends up in a tuple, because of `*args`. If you're passing a tuple as that one argument, well, then you get a tuple in a tuple.

Comment: did you see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315010/what-do-and-before-a-variable-name-mean-in-a-function-signature

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the syntax rule for having trailing commas in tuple definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992559/what-is-the-syntax-rule-for-having-trailing-commas-in-tuple-definitions)

Comment: Are you aware that both ``(1,)`` and ``(1, 2)`` are tuples? Note how both are of the form ``(..., ...)``.

Comment: so, the trailing comma is a good style of writing code and hence python prints those tuples with comma in the end?

Comment: The comma makes a tuple. ``(1,)`` is a tuple, ``(1)`` is not.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi as mhhabib pointed out trailing comma (,) is a good style of writing. ..

Comment: It's unclear what "good style" means. It's *the way* to represent tuples.

Comment: I think what @Daniele Lin says makes sense. I wanted to know why the comma was present even after I passed more than one tuple. Hope you all agree..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first output shows a comma because without it, `1` being the only element, `(1)` would be just a integer (parentheses are wrapping the expression `1`), `(1,)` is shown to differentiate tuples and simple parentheses.

in the second one, no trailing comma is needed to differentiate tuples, since there are more than one element.

In the third O/p, you are not passing `1` and `2`, but instead you're passing the whole `(1,2)`, so it shows only one item (which is `(1,2)`) in a tuple, and adds an extra comma. Same for the fourth: your passing the entire `((1,2), (3,4))`.

Answer (score -1):

In the function call `func(value2)` , you're passing a list of arguments. It should be passed as `func(*value2)`

`func(value2)` --> `func(((1, 2), (3, 4)))`

`func(*value2)` --> `func((1, 2), (3, 4))`

Comment: Thanks! my question was why is the comma trailing? even after passing more than one tuple. I assumed that once we pass multiple tuples the comma should not be present.

Comment: because without the * `((1, 2), (3, 4))` is being treated as a single entity. Count the number of braces in the output.