# python not accept keyword arguments

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I am trying to make my code NOT to accept keyword arguments just like some bulitins also do not accept keyword arguments, but, I am unable to do so. Here, is my thinking according to my limited understanding:-

```
def somefunc(a,b):
    print a,b

somefunc(10,20)
```

**Output:**

```
10 20
```

---

Now, When I run the following (I know this is not expected to be keyword argument in the function definition, but, **looking at the function call, it seems to be the same syntax as that of when calling a function which accepts keyword arguments**):

```
somefunc(b=10,a=20)
```

**Output:**

```
20 10
```

**I have 2 questions**:-

1. Looking at the function call `somefunc(b=10,a=20)` and not the function definition, this can seem to be either of a call to a function which accepts just normal arguments or a function which accepts keyword arguments. How does the interpreter differentiate between the two?
2. Is it possible to convert any of our function in a form so that it does not accept keyword arguments just like many of the builtins do?

**Why I want to do this at all?**
I am just checking if I can do this, so that I do not miss anything in understanding python in depth. I do knot know whether python allows that or not.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I am just checking if I can do this, so that I do not miss anything in understanding python in depth.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ad 1) Correct names are verified automatically by Python if they are called like `somefunct(name=value, ...)`. I don't need to remember the exact standard order of parameters and to verify it too "neurotic" by looking into the documentation every month at every usage, if I remember a function with nice descriptive names of parameters. A call with named parameters can be easily verified by a test or by use. On the contrary, the correct order of used parameters can be verified only by reading the documentation. Calling by named parameters is preferred over a very long list of positional parameters. Therefore the reported behavior is well-founded. (Short single letter parameters "a, b" don't help against mistakes of course.)

ad 2) **[Positional-only parameters](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#positional-only-parameters)** defined in Python code are possible in **Python 3.8 and newer** by a new function parameter syntax **`/`** to indicate that some function parameters must be specified positional and cannot be used as keyword arguments.

```py
def somefunc(a, b, /):
    print(a, b)
```

Originally it was possible only in C. Some well known builtin fast functions written in C with small fixed number of required parameters typically do not support calling with named parameters. (e.g. `hasattr`)

This is because they use only a fast simple header `...(... PyObject *args)` and therefore all named parameters are rejected automatically. (Python can never introspect into names of arguments in C source. :-)

Many other C functions have a header `...(... PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)` and they support exact list of names explicit by implementing much more complicated validation `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords`. These names must be written to docs strings manually.

---

Comment: I'm typing functions defined in C, and was looking for a way to let the user/static analyzer know that argument names are for clarity only, and are not accepted. Three years later, I just wanted to let you know, your edit helped me!

Answer (score 8):

You can use arbitrary argument lists to do this.  See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists

For example:

```
def somefunc(*args):
    print args[0], args[1]
```

Calling without keywords:

```
somefunc(10,20)
```

Gives:

```
10 20
```

Calling with keywords:

```
somefunc(a=10,b=20)
```

Gives an error:

```
TypeError: someFunc() got an unexpected keyword argument 'a'
```

It's unclear why you would want to do this though.

Comment: +1 - _It's unclear why you would want to do this though._ - just because you _can_ do it _doesn't_ mean that it is OK to do it.

Answer (score 4):

> Looking at the function call somefunc(b=10,a=20) and not the function definition, this can seem to be either of a call to a function which accepts just normal arguments or a function which accepts keyword arguments. How does the interpreter differentiate between the two?

Not sure if this is quite what you're asking, but if I understand you right, the answer is "it doesn't".  You can *call* the function with keywords no matter how the arguments are *defined* in the function.  If you pass any arguments using keyword syntax (e.g., `f(a=...)`), Python binds the corresponding values to the arguments with the same names in the function definition.  It doesn't matter whether a default value was defined.  The two kinds of function definition don't create different "kinds" of arguments, it's just that some of the arguments might have default values and others might not.  So whether you do `def f(a)` or `def f(a=2)`, you can still do `f(a=...)`.  The only restriction is that you have to pass/define positional arguments first (e.g., you can't do `def f(a=2, b)` or `f(a=2, 3)`).  See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419046/python-normal-arguments-vs-keyword-arguments).

As for the second part of your question, I'm not aware of any way to stop a Python function from accepting keyword-passed values for named arguments.  If you define only `*args` then it won't accept keyword arguments, but the positional arguments can't have separate names.

Comment: @BrenBarn: `You can call the function with keywords no matter how the arguments are defined in the function`. I understand that. But, I am saying that just by looking at the function call `somefunc(b=10,a=20)`, it can be confusing to judge whether the function definition expects 2 distinct arguments by the name: `a` and `b`, or does the function expect keyword arguments. Ain't it?

Comment: @GodMan: I think you're using "keyword arguments" in a strange way.  Do you mean *variable* keyword arguments (i.e., `**kwargs`)?  If so, then yes, you can't tell.  But that's not what "keyword arguments" means; keyword arguments are just arguments that are defined and/or passed by keyword (even if they're defined explicitly).  Functions defined `def f(a, b)` and `def f(a=2, b=3)` both accept distinct arguments by the names `a` and `b`, and in both cases you can pass these values either by position or by keyword.

Comment: @Marcin: I've edited to clarify that what you can't do is have named positional arguments that don't accept values passed by keyword.

Comment: @BrenBarn Awesome. No more upvote, because I voted your answer up in the first place ;)

Answer (score 3):

There isn't such a strong distinction in Python between keyword and positional arguments. In fact, it is as simple as:

Positional arguments are parsed in the *order they are listed in the function call*
Keyword arguments can be added *in any order*, but cannot come *before* positional arguments.

So, if you have this:

```
def foo(x):
    pass
```

You can do:

```
foo(1) # positional
foo(x=1) # keyword
```

But you cannot do `foo()` because you didn't supply a default value.

Similarly, if you have this:

```
def foo(x,y='hello'):
    pass

foo(1) # this works fine
foo() # this is invalid, as an argument without a default isn't passed
foo(y='hello',1) # error - positional arguments come before keyword arguments
```

Don't forget to read up on [arbitrary argument lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a very bad Python feature, and can lead to very unmaintainable and buggy code. Suppose you had a function:

```
def myurl(x, y):
    url = "{}:{}".format(x, y)
    return url
```

Although it might look like a good idea to enable replacing positional with keyword arguments don't ever do that. I'm surprised that there is no Python option that would prevent this function to be called with keyword arguments:

```
>> print myurl(x="localhost", y=8080)
```

If someone figures out the library would be more readable if written as:

```
def myurl(hostname, port):
    url = "{}:{}".format(hostname, port)
    return url
```

then the rest of the code that used keyword calling as `myurl(x="localhost", y=8080)` would fail:

```
TypeError: myurl() got an unexpected keyword argument 'x'
```

This means that your local function variable all of the sudden became a global variable! I was hoping this issue would be somehow addressed in Python 3.