# Is there a complete list of built-in functions that cannot be called with keyword argument?

Tags: python, arguments, python-c-api

People mentioned in answers [a1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24463222/2142577), [a2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12337182/2142577) that

> Due to the way the Python C-level APIs developed, a lot of built-in
>   functions and methods don't actually have names for their arguments.

I found it really annoying cause I'm not be able to know it by looking at the doc. For instance, [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

> eval(expression, globals=None, locals=None)

Then I wrote this line of code

```
print(eval('a+b', globals={'a':1, 'b':2}))
```

and got `TypeError: eval() takes no keyword arguments`. So is there a complete list of functions of this kind? How do I know if a function is allowed to have keyword arguments?

Comment: Not only that but there are bugs with this, try `sorted(iterable=[])` vs `sorted(iterable=None)`.

Comment: I guess that all such "traps" are actually bugs, and should be reported: both ``sorted()`` and the keyword arguments documented but not accepted.  (Fwiw PyPy generally accepts keyword arguments.)

Comment: It has been reported IIRC. (I think I read it from the bug tracker)

Comment: @ArminRigo What's more disappointing is that this isn't even mentioned in doc.

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue26729

Comment: @laike9m: that's why they are bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3.5 you can inspect the `__text_signature__` of the built-in function:

```
>>> eval.__text_signature__
'($module, source, globals=None, locals=None, /)'
```

or

```
>>> abs.__text_signature__
'($module, x, /)'
>>> abs(x=5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: abs() takes no keyword arguments
```

(`x` cannot be used as a keyword argument)

The `/` means that the arguments following that can be used as keyword arguments. C.f.

```
>>> compile.__text_signature__
'($module, /, source, filename, mode, flags=0,\n        dont_inherit=False, optimize=-1)'
>>> compile(source='foo', filename='bar', mode='exec')
<code object <module> at 0x7f41c58f0030, file "bar", line 1>
```

---

Of course there are bugs even in 3.5:

```
>>> sorted.__text_signature__
'($module, iterable, key=None, reverse=False)'
```

though according to [issue 26729 in the Python bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue26729), there ought to be `/` after the `iterable` as the `iterable` cannot be used as a keyword argument.

---

Unfortunately this information is not yet available in the Python documentation itself.