# Using a function inside a function and its variable as a variable

Tags: python

Assume for example that I am writing a function for the following code (in pandas module):

```
myData.sort_values(by=myVariable, ascending=False)
```

Now, I want to create a function whose variables are *data, variable* and *ascending*.

```
sort(data=mydata, variable=myvariable, ascending=False)
```

The below function gives an error, because whether ascending is true or false is not given in second line:

```
def sort(data,variable,ascending=False):
    data.sort_values(by=variable, ascending)
```

Although it would work, I do not want to change variable name such as:

```
def sort(data,variable,asc=False):
    data.sort_values(by=variable, ascending=asc)
```

One last approach would be to create a variable inside the function:

```
def sort(data,variable,ascending=False):
    asc = ascending
    data.sort_values(by=variable, ascending=asc)
```

but it looks somewhat confusing. Is there an alternative approach to use the same variable in this case?

Note: the question is not related with pandas module, it is just an example.

**Edit:** I have clearly stated my problem and showed what I have tried. I did not understand the reason for the downvote.

Comment: There are functions in python that can take positional arguments and keyword only arguments. If there is such a keyword only constraint set on the arguments, you can't call it as positional arguments. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54252179/how-to-create-a-python-function-which-take-only-positional-arguments-and-no-keyw).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried:

```
def sort(data,variable,ascending=False):
    data.sort_values(by=variable, ascending=ascending)
```

Comment: This did not produce an error, but it didn't work either

Comment: Then you should open a new question for that error and accept this answer as correct

Comment: Thanks, I tried this with another dataset and it works.

Answer (score 0):

> The below function gives an error, because whether ascending is true or false is not given in second line:

```
def sort(data,variable,ascending=False):
    data.sort_values(by=variable, ascending)
```

No; it gives an error because positional arguments cannot come after keyword arguments. Like the error message says: `SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument`.

The way to fix this is as in the other answer, using `ascending=ascending`. The idea is that the arguments for the function call are in a separate namespace from the current local variables.

If it "didn't work", then you need to ask a new question and properly explain the expected and actual results, with a complete example that other users can test locally.