# Distinction between Default Argument Values and Keyword Arguments?

Tags: python

Are default argument values perceived as keyword arguments by Python? I'm not able understand the distinction

I can't understand this thread: [Normal arguments vs. keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419046/python-normal-arguments-vs-keyword-arguments)

On a side note, most tutorials and video series seemed to be geared towards *Python 2.**. Should I learn *Python 3* instead *Python 2* or can I make the transition later easily? I'm just learning this out of curiosity.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both concepts are (mostly) distinct.

On function definition side, you have named parameters which have names, and you have variadic extensions, one for positional arguments (giving a tuple) and one for keyboard arguments (giving a dict).

Example:

```
def f(a, b=5, *c, **d): return a, b, c, d
```

This function has two named parameters (`a`and `b`) which can be used positional or via keyword. `c` and `d` take all others given.

You can call this function with positional arguments as well as with keyword arguments.

```
f(1)
f(a=1)
```

both return

```
1, 5, (), {}
```

because positional and keyword arguments are assigned to the named parameters.

You can as well do

```
f(a=5, foo=12) or f(5, foo=12) # -> 5, 5, (), {'foo': 12}
f(1, 2, 3) # -> 1, 2, (3,), {}
```

In the last example, the positional arguments 1 and 2 are given to the named parameters `a` and `b`; the exceeding 3 is put into the tuple `c`.

You cannot do

```
f(b=90) # no value for a
f(12, a=90) # two values for a
```

If there are still unclearities, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see people tend to use both term interchangeably

I see that this question is quite old , but will add my two-cents anyway.

The term Default-Arguments ( a.k.a  "Default-Parameters") is the term you will generally  use while ***defining*** your function; within the header of the def statement:

When defining your function you can view it *in your head* as follows:

```
def function1(positional_parameter, default_parameter="default-output"):
    pass
```

However you will generally use the term "Keyword-Argument" when you're attempting to ***call*** a function.

when calling the function you can view it *in your head*  as follows:

```
function1(positional_argument, keyword_argument="change-output")
```

- hope this makes sense *