# Assign variables to the list elements, without knowing it's length

Tags: python, list, variable-assignment

Not sure how to form corectly, but the problem is related to a shapefile(python library) function of writing a new row, which requires to write variables..
From my data I'm creating a list, which I thought I can cast to tuple and will solve my problem, but nah.. I doesn't go so easy...

The function is asking this:
`w.record(a, b, c, d....)` or `w.record('a', 256, 25.2444, 'd'....)`
My data is in a list, but the list length is not known my default, it depends form the input data and the right length is important!

I could also write `w.record(list[0], list[1]...list[len(list)-1])`, but then I have to create this automatically and not sure how could I do that.

Btw, I use an old python: 2.5... (not my choise)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly; but I Python supports functions with [arbitrary argument lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists), is that what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 kinds of `argument` in a function declaration: -

- Positional Argument
- Default Argument (or, keyword argument - in the form: - `a = 5`)
- Non-Keyword Argument
- Keyword Argument (or, dictionary type keyword argument)

**A typical function declaration goes like this: -**

```
func(positional_args, keyword_args,
                     *tuple_grp_nonkw_args, **dict_grp_kw_args)
```

You need `non-keyword` argument, which take extra argument and store them as `tuple`:

```
w.record(*yourvalues)
```

Similarly `keyword` argument, takes `dictionary` as input. They are denoted with `**kwarg`.

- All the keyword arguments after the non-keyword arguments go into `**kwarg`
- And all the keyword arguments before the non-keyword arguments are default arguments

**For E.G: -**

```
// nkwarg takes a list
// kwarg takes a dictionary
def foo(arg, defaultarg = 5, *nkwarg, **kwarg):
    print arg
    print defaultarg
    print nkwarg
    print kwarg


foo("hello", ["how", "are", "you"], a = 3, b = 4)
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
hello
5
(['how', 'are', 'you'],)
{'a': 3, 'b': 4}
```

Comment: but if I have a list: l=['Mok', 'Union_80vH_50vH', 13867, 32, '11:20:13.077', '523.343', '29.1', '29.09.2012', '13:17:02.077', '11:19:58.077', 1, 35, '90', '523.343', 1348917598], how does it go?

Comment: @najuste It will be stored in `*nkwarg`. `*` mark is used to make  a parameter take any number of values. Basically it takes a variable length list.

Comment: @najuste  You can take a look at this link: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419046/python-normal-arguments-vs-keyword-arguments and http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/keywordArgs.html

Comment: Thanks, did not know about * things (newbie). But if I pass a list, as a result from such I again get a list.. Ok, kind of find I can use w.record(foo(*list)) but that's agian happens with two brackets and so does not work..
I got it!! Sorry, I just tested wrongly.. uf..

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(hello, *args):
 print hello

 for each in args:
     print each

if __name__ == '__main__':
 foo("LOVE", ["lol", "lololol"])
```