# Python 3, multiple str functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

As far as I know, Python doesn't support function overloading, but in Python documentation

[link to py3k doc](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str)

seems that there are 2 different str methods, `str(object='')` and `str(object=b'', encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')`

How are defined these functions? When is the first invoked and when the second?

Can I create my own `f(o='')` and `f(o=b'')` functions (makes sense)?

**UPDATE**

Output for `str(b'abc','utf-8')` is `abc` but

output for `str(b'abc')` is `b'abc'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, python doesn't support overloading *because it doesn't need to*. Python documentation often shows different ways of calling a method to illustrate different uses, but there is only one `str()` callable (a type in this case).

In this case, `str()` accepts multiple keyword arguments, which have default values if not specified. The `str()` type then uses the those extra keyword arguments, if specified, to interpret a `b''` byte string argument. If no keyword arguments were passed in, `str()` behaves differently.

In other words, `str()` adjusts it's behaviour based on wether or not the keyword arguments have been supplied. If that is the case and the first argument is a bytestring or bytearray,  it'll decode that argument to unicode text, using the extra keyword arguments to control the decoding process.

You can define your own function that'll behave the same way as regards to the keyword arguments, checking the type of the first argument:

```
def f(o, encoding=None, errors=None):
    if encoding is None and errors is None:
        return o.__str__()

    if isinstance(o, str):
        raise TypeError('decoding str is not supported')

    if not isinstance(o, (bytes, bytesarray)):
        raise TypeError('coercing to str: need bytes, bytearray'
             'or buffer-like object, %s found' % type(o).__name__)
    return o.decode(encoding, errors)
```

Comment: Your fuction example is not the str function behavior in python3 output for `str(b'abc','utf-8')` is `abc` but
output for `str(b'abc')` is `b'abc'`

Comment: @JoseLuis: I remembered it wrong. Updated the answer to better reflect what `str()` does. The same principle applies though.

Comment: @JoseLuis: I've referenced the C implementation of `str()` and the `f` function is a good approximation in Python of what it does now. Good enough for illustration purposes in any case.

Comment: ok, that means that py3k documentation is wrong, or at least not clear, in two points. There is only one str() function (and no two), and the function definition is `str(object='', encoding=None, errors='strict')` (and not `str(object=b'', encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')` )

Comment: @JoseLuis: The default encoding for conversion *is* UTF-8; see http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode and http://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html, and as I stated in my answer, the two behaviours are separate and thus *documented* distinctly. Don't confuse a misunderstanding about how the  documentation tries to provide clarity with being wrong.

Comment: Where can I find the C implementation of str()? I downloaded the Python source code, but I don't how is structured and I can't find it

Comment: `Objects/unicodeobject.c`, use the [C API](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html) as a guide; constructor is `unicode_new()`.

Comment: @JoseLuis: The C API has to do more work to parse arguments, but it doesn't do it quite like what you used in the suggested edit. You'll need to study the C API some more, I think.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's only one `str()`.

It is shown twice for the sake of clarity (that is, to demonstrate different use cases).

You can achieve similar effects in your code by using default arguments, positional argument and keyword arguments. See [Python normal arguments vs. keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419046/python-normal-arguments-vs-keyword-arguments)