# Django Get Method, Invalid Literal for Base 10

Tags: python, django

This ties into mt question from earlier.  I've looked a few answers to similar issues, but I'm not sure how they apply here.

I'm trying to use GET methods to creat content on a Django Webserver.  When i type the following url:

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/maps/createEvent/?name=explosion&reporter=nathaniel&description=something%20exploded&lat=99&lon=99&timestamp=2434253
```

I get this error:

```
    invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'explosion'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/maps/createEvent/?name=explosion&reporter=nathaniel&description=something%20exploded&lat=99&lon=99&timestamp=2434253
Django Version: 1.5.2
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'explosion'
```

Here's the url in question:

```
url(r'^createEvent/$', views.createEvent, name='createEvent')
```

And the View:

```
def createEvent(request):
e = Event(request.GET['name'],request.GET['reporter'],request.GET['description'],
           request.GET['lat'],request.GET['lon'],request.GET['timestamp'])
e.save()

return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('maps:event_detail', args=(e.id,)))
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of the `Event` model?

Comment: Does Event constructor expect first parameter as integer? or better say attempts converting string to int?

Comment: I actually just figured it out, I'll post my answer below.  Thanks guys.

Comment: Sometime all it takes is asking the question to realize the answer ;) Love it when that happens to me lol

Comment: Haha yea, I can't post the answer for 8 hours since I have no rep, but basically I needed to put Event(<fieldname>=<val>,.....) in the constructor.  I'm not used to that format.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Django enough to have spotted that right away. The notion is called [keyword arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419046/python-normal-arguments-vs-keyword-arguments) and can actually be really useful.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add a [`get_absolute_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_absolute_url) method to your `Event` model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    # your fields go here

    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('maps:event_detail', self.pk)
```

You need to do something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def createEvent(request):
   e = Event.objects.create(name=request.GET.get('name'),
                            reporter=request.GET.get('reporter'),
                            description=request.GET.get('description'),
                            lat=request.GET.get('lat'),
                            lon=request.GET.get('lon'),
                            timestamp=request.GET.get('timestamp'))

   return redirect(e)
```

[`create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#create) will automatically save the object; and the [`redirect` shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) automatically uses the `get_absolute_url` method if passed an instance of a model.

Or, you can use a `ModelForm` - if this is something the user is entering:

In a file called `forms.py`, add this:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Event

class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
```

Now your view becomes very simple:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import EventForm

def createEvent(request):
    form = EventForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
       e = form.save()
       return redirect(e)
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

Your template (the `form.html`) now is:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

As this is a common pattern (creating new things for models), django provides a generic [`CreateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview) to speed things up:

```
from django.generic.views import CreateView

class CreateEvent(CreateView):
     model = Event
     template_name = 'form.html'
```

All the above code snippets do the exact same logic (except for the first one, which just saves an object).  As you can see, django provides quick shortcuts for common tasks.

Comment: Hey,thanks for this!  It's a great answer.  Turns out the actual bug I'm facing is the key value pairing from your createEvent() example.  I figured that out last night, but since you got that+ about a dozen other thigns I'm going to call it answered.  If you want to edit it to specifically point out my syntax error I'll accept.