# Numpy apply_along_axis function

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use numpys apply_along_axis with a function who needs more than one argument.

```
test_array = np.arange(10)
test_array2 = np.arange(10)

def example_func(a,b):
   return a+b

np.apply_along_axis(example_func, axis=0, arr=test_array, args=test_array2)
```

In the manual: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html there is the parameter args for additional parameters. But if I try to add that parameter python returns an error:

*TypeError: apply_along_axis() got an unexpected keyword argument 'args'*

or if I don't use args an argument is missing

*TypeError: example_func() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)*

This here is just an example code and I know I could solve that in different ways like using numpy.add or np.vectorize. But my question is if I can use numpys apply_along_axis function with a function which uses more than one argument.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the `*args` in the signature `numpy.apply_along_axis(func1d, axis, arr, *args)` means that there are some other *[positional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419046/python-normal-arguments-vs-keyword-arguments)* could be passed.

If you want to add two numpy arrays elementwise, just use `+` operator:

```
In [112]: test_array = np.arange(10)
     ...: test_array2 = np.arange(10)

In [113]: test_array+test_array2
Out[113]: array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18])
```

Remove the keywords `axis=`, `arr=`, `args=` should also work:

```
In [120]: np.apply_along_axis(example_func, 0, test_array, test_array2)
Out[120]: array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18])
```

Comment: Not sure if you read my question right. My question is if or how I can use apply_along_axis with a function which uses more than one argument. The function in my question is just a non-sense example to show what I want to do.

Answer (score 14):

I just want to briefly elaborate on [zhangxaochen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21812414/3833166), in case that helps someone. Let's use an example where we want to greet a list of people with a particular greeting.

```
def greet(name, greeting):
    print(f'{greeting}, {name}!')

names = np.array(["Luke", "Leia"]).reshape(2,1)
```

Since `apply_along_axis` accepts `*args`, we can [pass an arbitrary number of arguments to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3394898/3833166), which in this case will each be passed along to `func1d`.

#### Avoiding Syntax Error

In order to avoid a `SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument` we have to label the argument:

```
np.apply_along_axis(func1d=greet, axis=1, arr=names, greeting='Hello')
```

#### More Than One Additional Argument

If we also had a function that took even more arguments

```
def greet_with_date(name, greeting, date):
    print(f'{greeting}, {name}! Today is {date}.')
```

we could use it in either of the following ways:

```
np.apply_along_axis(greet_with_date, 1, names, 'Hello', 'May 4th')
np.apply_along_axis(func1d=greet_with_date, axis=1, arr=names, date='May 4th', greeting='Hello')
```

Note that we don't need to worry about the order of the keyword arguments.