# Order of parameters and arguments in function definition and function call

Tags: python

At the end of the day studying parameters and arguments in python , I finally made the following conclusion

**Order of parameters in function definition**

```
def foo ( non-optional parameters , optional parameters , *args , **kwargs):
```

**Order of arguments in function call**

```
foo( non-keyword arguments , keyword arguments )
```

Just want to know whether there is any exception to this in python world....
Further if there are any other types of arguments/parameters please do comment...

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python normal arguments vs. keyword arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419046/python-normal-arguments-vs-keyword-arguments)

Comment: Allowed syntax for [Python 2.x](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) and allowed for [Python 3.x](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) - note the difference for specifying end of positional arguments in Python 3.x is discussed in [PEP 3102](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Argument Matching Syntax**
summarizes the syntax that invokes the special argument-matching modes.
Function argument-matching forms Syntax Location Interpretation

1. **func(value)**       Caller Normal argument: matched by position
2. **func(name=value)**  Caller Keyword argument: matched by name
3. **func(*iterable)**   Caller Pass all objects in iterable as individual positional arguments
4. **func(**dict)**      Caller Pass all key/value pairs in dict as individual keyword arguments

below are for defining functions......

1. **def func(name)**    Function Normal argument: matches any passed value by position or name
2. **def func(name=value)** Function Default argument value, if not passed in the call
3. **def func(*name)**        Function Matches and collects remaining positional arguments in a tuple
4. **def func(**name)**     Function Matches and collects remaining keyword arguments in a dictionary
5. **def func(*other, name)** Function Arguments that must be passed by keyword only in calls (3.X)
6. **def func(*, name=value)** Function Arguments that must be passed by keyword only in calls (3.X)

Answer (score 0):

The [Python Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/index.html#the-python-language-reference) describes the syntax and “core semantics” of the language. It is terse, but attempts to be exact and complete. There you find descriptions of lexical analysis and syntax using a modified [BNF grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) notation.

Usually all Python implementation follow this grammar. Thus there should be no exceptions on this grammar. If yes, you should refer to the implementation-specific documentation.

[Function definitions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions)

```
decorated      ::=  decorators (classdef | funcdef)
decorators     ::=  decorator+
decorator      ::=  "@" dotted_name ["(" [argument_list [","]] ")"] NEWLINE
funcdef        ::=  "def" funcname "(" [parameter_list] ")" ":" suite
dotted_name    ::=  identifier ("." identifier)*
parameter_list ::=  (defparameter ",")*
                    (  "*" identifier ["," "**" identifier]
                    | "**" identifier
                    | defparameter [","] )
defparameter   ::=  parameter ["=" expression]
sublist        ::=  parameter ("," parameter)* [","]
parameter      ::=  identifier | "(" sublist ")"
funcname       ::=  identifier
```

[Calls](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls)

```
call                 ::=  primary "(" [argument_list [","]
                          | expression genexpr_for] ")"
argument_list        ::=  positional_arguments ["," keyword_arguments]
                            ["," "*" expression] ["," keyword_arguments]
                            ["," "**" expression]
                          | keyword_arguments ["," "*" expression]
                            ["," "**" expression]
                          | "*" expression ["," "*" expression] ["," "**" expression]
                          | "**" expression
positional_arguments ::=  expression ("," expression)*
keyword_arguments    ::=  keyword_item ("," keyword_item)*
keyword_item         ::=  identifier "=" expression
```