# Flask - Using jsonify properly

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm having some trouble in understanding how `jsonify` works even though I went through the documentation. As you can see below, I'm calling the `lookup()` function which returns a dictionary, then I'm trying to jsonify it.

```
@app.route("/articles")
def articles():

    a = lookup(33496)
    return jsonify([link=a["link"], title = a["title"]])       #invalid syntax error
```

my `helpers.py`:

```
import feedparser
import urllib.parse

def lookup(geo):
    """Looks up articles for geo."""       #this function already parses the 'link' and 'title' form rss feed

    # check cache for geo
    if geo in lookup.cache:
        return lookup.cache[geo]

    # get feed from Google
    feed = feedparser.parse("http://news.google.com/news?geo={}&output=rss".format(urllib.parse.quote(geo, safe="")))

    # if no items in feed, get feed from Onion
    if not feed["items"]:
        feed = feedparser.parse("http://www.theonion.com/feeds/rss")

    # cache results
    lookup.cache[geo] = [{"link": item["link"], "title": item["title"]} for item in feed["items"]]

    # return results
    return lookup.cache[geo]

# initialize cache
lookup.cache = {}
```

The error that I'm getting is of invalid syntax. Any idea into what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `dict` syntax is wrong. You can read about more in [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

The code that I think you are trying for is as follows:

```
@app.route("/articles")
def articles():
    a = lookup(33496)
    return jsonify({"link" : a["link"], "title" : a["title"]})
```

Specifically you should use curly braces instead of brackets (`{}`) and colon (`:`) instead of equals sign.

Another option is to let `jsonify()` to do the conversion (as pointed out in the other answer):

```
@app.route("/articles")
def articles():
    a = lookup(33496)
    return jsonify(link = a["link"], title = a["title"])
```

Nevertheless, I think you would be well advised to use create a `dict`. It becomes more flexible when you need to create larger JSON objects.

Hope this helps.

Comment: what's the purpose of jsonify then, if you need to explicitly do the conversion to json?

Comment: Yea @Jari, the problem is that I already edited it the way that you pointed out using `jsonify()` but I'm getting some syntax errors.

Comment: I now tried using your first example and I'm getting the errors too. Hmm

Comment: Also, the point of jsonify() is to have a standard way of converting different content (be it dict, array or arguments) to JSON format that Flask can then return over HTTP.

Comment: Actually it's working now, I had some misspellings. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You dont need the square brackets, get rid of them.

```
return jsonify(link=a["link"], title=a["title"])
             # ^At this point                 ^ and this one.
```

[Read about keyword arguments in python.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1419160/227884)

Comment: I got rid of it but I'm getting the same invalid syntax error

Comment: I'll go over the link, maybe that's where I'm going wrong.