# how assign list attributes to a class python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a class student and then assign him or her a subject (maths, science, etc.) and then the grade by subject.

Basically, I have created a class student with name, gender,etc. Then I need to add more than one subject.

But i dont understand how one student object can get more than one subject and probably a greade per subject.

```
class student:
   def __init__(self,name,age,gender,subject):
     self.name = name
     self.age = age
     self.gender = gender
     self.subject = subject

   def __str__(self):
     return ('{},{},{},{}'.format(self.name,self.age,self.gender,self.subject))


new = student('Alan',17,'M','Science')
```

Please if someone can help me to clarify a little bit I appreciate.

thanks

Comment: Your explanation is a little confusing.  Do you have some code that would illustrate what you want to do?

Comment: You don't assign one class to the other, the student object will have a subject *object* as a property.  This could be done in the `__init__()` for the student and/or in a student object method.

Comment: @cdarke I follow you, then I dont need a class for subjects, you said just added as an attribut but then if the same student has 10 subjects and I just have one attribute subjects how the objects student will catch 10 times the attribute subject? that is what confuse to me. thanks

Comment: just use a list of subjects, initialise it as `[ ]` and `append` each one as it is added.

Comment: I think your original question title was better than the one you changed it to in revision 4.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish this task. One solution is to *not* specify the subject when creating the student. Instead, you would create the student object and then add subjects to it.

For example:

```
student = Student(name="John Smith")
for subject_name in ("Math", "Science", "Literature"):
    student.add_subject(subject_name)
```

That gives you a new student who has three subjects. The `add_subject` method might look something like this:

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender):
        ...
        self.subjects = {}
        ...
    def add_subject(self, name):
        self.subjects[name] = Subject(name)
```

To assign grades you would do something like this, perhaps

```
student.add_grade("Math", "A")
student.add_grade("Science", "B")
student.add_grade("Literature", "C")
```

`add_grade` would then take the grade name, look up the subject object from `self.subjects`, and call a method on that subject object to add the grade.

For example:

```
def add_grade(self, subject_name, grade):
    subject = self.subjects[subject_name]
    subject.add_grade(grade)
```

Your class `Subject` could be something very simple:

```
class Subject(self):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.grade = None
    def add_grade(self, grade):
        self.grade = grade
```

Note: the above assumes you want a single grade per subject. If you want multiple grades, you can change `self.grade` to be `self.grades` and have it be a list.

Comment: @Farhan.K: yes. Thanks, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Just to confirm buddy then grade is going to be a student attribute as well.

Comment: @AndresAngel: no, grade is an attribute on the subject.

Comment: buddy sorry i dont see that in your code so subject is really another class or  otherwise is a function of the class student?

Comment: @AndresAngel `Subject` is a class. An instance of `Subject` is created inside of `add_subject`. The grade is an attribute of the subject, and is added with the `add_grade` method of the subject.

Comment: could you please include the code how you created your class subject pls. thanks

Comment: @AndresAngel: ok, I added a basic `Subject` class definition.

Comment: trying buddy !!

Comment: buddy how you return in the methode __str__ for the object student the subjects added?

Comment: @AndresAngel: I honestly think you can figure that out if you just try. All the data you need is available.

Comment: Im adding a grade already using new.add_grade('maths', 5)

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I gather that you have already worked with entity relations (ERDs), which is why you are thinking in terms of associations -- which is good. I'm assuming this is homework, so I don't want to give away too much. However, the code below should get you started.

```
from typing import List, Dict


class CollegeClass:
    def __init__(self, class_code: str, name: str):
        self.class_code = class_code  #type: str
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.class_code}, {self.name}"

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)


class Student:
    def __init__(self):
        self.current_classes = dict()   # type: Dict[str, CollegeClass]

    def enroll(self, college_class: CollegeClass):
        if college_class.class_code in self.current_classes:
            print("The student is already taking the class.")
            return
        self.current_classes[college_class.class_code] = college_class


if __name__ == '__main__':

    math = CollegeClass("mth101", "Intro to Math")
    english = CollegeClass("eng201", "Intro to Fiction")

    eric_praline = Student()
    eric_praline.enroll(math)
    eric_praline.enroll(english)

    for _, cls in eric_praline.current_classes.items():
        print(cls)
```

Comment: I failed to address grading -- of which there are many ways. A simple solution is to have a dictionary whose key is the class_code, and whose value is either the letter grade, or even another class that holds information about how the student did in the class (grade, attendance, scores, etc). I can edit the answer to elaborate if you need.

Answer (score 0):

`Class Student` represents just a type of people

`Object of class Student` represents a particular student, e.g. John Smith

`Class Subject` represents something students can learn in general

`Object of class Subject` represents a particular class students can take, e.g. Math 2017

`Grade` does not belong in either of these, because it only makes sense with a combination of both. So I would suggest creating some data storage, e.g. a list of tuples to store a grade for each combination of student/subject objects you want to keep track of, e.g.

```
Grades = [
    (john_smith, math_2017, 'A+'),
    ...    
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Subject(object):
    def __init__(self, name, grade=None):
        self.name = name
        self.grade = grade

class student:
    def __init__(self,name,age,gender, subjects=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender
        self.subjects = {}
        for sub in subjects:
            self.subjects[sub] = Subject(sub)

# Create new student with 2 subjects (Art and Science)
new = student('Alan',17,'M', subjects=['Art', 'Science'])


# You can wrap the following processes in functions if so desired

# Add a new subject later on (Math)
new.subjects['Math'] = Subject('Math')

# Add grades
new.subjects['Art'].grade = 'C'
new.subjects['Science'].grade = 'A+'
new.subjects['Math'].grade = 'B-'

# Get a list of subjects and grades
print([(sub.name, sub.grade) for _, sub in new.subjects.items()])

>>>[('Art', 'C'), ('Science', 'A+'), ('Math', 'B-')]
```

Answer (score 0):

> But i [don't] understand how one student object can get more than one subject and probably a [grade] per subject.

Pass in a dictionary of `{subject: grade}` pairs.

**Code**

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender, subjects=None):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender

        # Handle mutable keyword defaults
        if subjects is None:
            self.subjects = {}
        else:
            self.subjects = subjects

    def __repr__(self):
        return ("{0.name}, {0.age}, {0.gender}, {0.subjects}".format(self))


subjects = {"Math": "A", "Biology": "B-", "Chemistry": "A"}
s = Student("Joe", 20, "M", subjects=subjects)
s
# Joe, 20, M, {'Math': 'A', 'Chemistry': 'A', 'Biology': 'B-'}

s.subjects["Math"]
# 'A'
```

---

Assigning `None` to a [keyword argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419046/python-normal-arguments-vs-keyword-arguments) is a convention for avoiding a [well-known gotcha](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments) when assigning mutable arguments, e.g. lists, dictionaries.  The lines that handle `subjects` is equivalent to this one-liner:

```
self.subjects = {} if subjects is None else subjects
```

The `__repr__()` method was defined, which you may wish to include along with `__str__()`.