# Sequence of arguments in Python scripting for abaqus

Tags: python, abaqus

I have written the section assignment command in .py file with its arguments written in random order and ran it on am model in abaqusbut i am getting error.
Does the sequence of arguments for a command in Python scripting of abaqus matter ?

Comment: you need to show the code and the error

Answer (score 0):

The `SectionAssignment` command may have a default order of arguments, but it's safer to use the [keyword arguments syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419046/python-normal-arguments-vs-keyword-arguments).

From `Section 44.1.1 SectionAssignment(...)` in the Abaqus v6.14 Scripting Reference Guide, the required arguments are *region* and *sectionName*, while optional arguments are *thicknessAssignment*, *offset*, *offsetType*, and *offsetField*. Your syntax should thus look like

`mdb.models[modelName].parts[partName].SectionAssignment(region=regionName, sectionName=sectionString, ...)`

or

`mdb.models[modelName].rootAssembly.SectionAssignment(region=regionName, sectionName=sectionString, ...)`

rather than passing arguments in a random order.