# Extracting arg values from string formatted by inspect.formatargvalues

Tags: python, string, parsing

I'm trying to parse a string that has been formatted using [`inspect.formatargvalues`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.formatargvalues) and I want to be able to extract the argument values and save them in a dictionary.

Here are some examples of the text:

```
CALL function.a(timeout_secs=10)
CALL function.b(x=something good (happy days, ABC 123), y_z=None, check_this=True, check_this_2=None, extra_info=None, press=False, timeout_secs=30)
CALL function.c(key='A_B')
CALL function.d(target=<Tab.Chrome: 'tab-chrome'>)
CALL function.e(music_type=<MusicType.ALBUM: 1>, term=None, genre=None, results=True)
CALL function.f(button='END', delay=None)
```

At the moment I'm extracting the parameters using regex to get:

```
timeout_secs=10
x=something good (happy days, ABC 123), y_z=None, check_this=True, check_this_2=None, extra_info=None, press=False, timeout_secs=30
key='A_B'
target=<Tab.Chrome: 'tab-chrome'>
music_type=<MusicType.ALBUM: 1>, term=None, genre=None, results=True
button='END', delay=None
```

Then I'm splitting on ',' and then converting the array into a dictionary.

```
dict(parameter.split("=") for parameter in array_of_parameters)
```

This works for the most part but obviously breaks when parsing:

```
x=something good (happy days, ABC 123), y_z=None, check_this=True, check_this_2=None, extra_info=None, press=False, timeout_secs=30
```

Is there a way to convert the arguments to a dictionary where it covers all these scenarios?

Comment: Could you use keyword arguments instead of named arguments in your functions?  Keyword arguments would make all of your arguments accessible via a dictionary.  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419046/python-normal-arguments-vs-keyword-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419046/python-normal-arguments-vs-keyword-arguments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to find a solution that is guaranteed to work in all cases, since the argument values can contain anything and this isn't a proper data format designed to be parsed. Here is something that works a bit better:

```
import re

line = 'x=something good (happy days, ABC 123), y_z=None, check_this=True, check_this_2=None, extra_info=None, press=False, timeout_secs=30'

print(re.findall(r'(?:^|, )(\w+)=(.+?)(?=$|, \w+=)', line))
# [('x', 'something good (happy days, ABC 123)'), ('y_z', 'None'), ('check_this', 'True'), ('check_this_2', 'None'), ('extra_info', 'None'), ('press', 'False'), ('timeout_secs', '30')]
```

Explanation:

1. `(?:^|, )`: the argument must be at the start of the string or preceded by a comma and space. This is a non-capturing group to contain the effect of `|` while not appearing in the results of `findall`.
2. `(\w+)`: the argument name
3. `(.+?)`: the argument value.
4. `(?=$|, \w+=)`: the argument value must be followed by the end of the string or another argument. This is a lookahead assertion instead of just a non-capturing group so that the match doesn't consume the string. Otherwise `findall` only finds every second argument since it only finds non-overlapping matches.