# Python __init__ * argument

Tags: python, init

So I'm pretty new to Python and there is this library I want to work with. However there is an argument in the constructor of the class which I can't find anything about.

**init** method looks like this:

`def __init__(self, ain1, ain2, bin1, bin2, *, microsteps=16):`

What does the * do? As far as I know the self is just the object itself and the others are just arguments. But what's the * ?

Link to the full class:
[check line 73](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_Motor/blob/master/adafruit_motor/stepper.py)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10):

In Python 3, adding `*` to a function's signature forces calling code to pass every argument defined after the asterisk as a keyword argument:

```
>> def foo(a, *, b):
..     print('a', a, 'b', b)

>> foo(1, 2)
TypeError: foo() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

>> foo(1, b=2)
a 1 b 2
```

In Python 2 this syntax is invalid.

Answer (score 4):

The `*` indicates something called [keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419046/normal-arguments-vs-keyword-arguments). Basically, this means you must specify the names of the parameters after the `*`. For example, if you had this method:

```
def somemethod(arg1, *, arg2):
    pass
```

you can call it this way:

```
somemethod(0, arg2=0)
```

but not this way:

```
somemethod(0, 0)
```

Using the `*` forces the user to specify what arguments are getting what values.