# Star (*) as a parameter in python function

Tags: python

I was looking at the definition of the `glob` function and I noticed that the second parameter was simply `*`.

```
def glob(pathname, *, recursive=False):
    """Return a list of paths matching a pathname pattern.
    [...]
    """
    return list(iglob(pathname, recursive=recursive))
```

What is the point of the `*`?

Comment: Correction: *parameter*, not *argument*

Comment: @wjandrea I'm not a native english speaker, would you please explain the difference or link a source which explains it? In swedish "parameter" means argument, also in italian we don't have a word to say argument because "argomento" is a false friend, so I always used "parametro" as a translation for "argument".

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO [What is the difference between arguments and parameters? - Python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-is-the-difference-between-arguments-and-parameters)

Comment: @wjandrea thank you a lot! In italian we used to call them "parametri formali" (for "parameters") and "parametri attuali" (for "arguments"), now I got it.

Comment: @wjandrea finally edited the question, 3y later :p.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

The `*` indicates the end of the positional arguments. Every argument after that can only be specified by keyword. This is defined in [PEP 3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/)

```
>>> def foo1(a, b=None):
...     print(a, b)
...
>>> def foo2(a, *, b=None):
...     print(a, b)
...
>>> foo1(1, 2)
1 2
>>> foo2(1, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo1() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
>>> foo2(1, b=2)
1 2
```

Comment: Interestingly, TensorFlow uses `_sentinel` as a first argument to some of its functions to prevent positional parameters. I'm wondering why they don't simply use `*`.

Comment: @AdamSmith I think you mean keyword only arguments, i.e. PEP 3102.  PEP 570 seems to use `/` to define "Positional-Only Parameters"

Comment: @BiBi: Python 2 support. Python 2 doesn't have this syntax.

Comment: @SamMason sorry, you're right -- good catch! (and thanks for the edit, user2357112)

Answer (score 10):

All arguments after the `*` must have their name explicitly specified. For example, if you had this function:

```
def somefunction(a,*,b):
    pass
```

You could write this:

```
somefunction(0, b=0)
```

but not this:

```
somefunction(0, 0)
```

Comment: You have answered 2 post with the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53795545/python-init-argument/53795611#53795611 you should mark as a duplicate :-)