# parameter '*' in pycryptodome

Tags: python, parameters

> ```
> Crypto.Cipher.<algorithm>.new(key, mode, *, nonce=None, mac_len=None)
> ```
>
> Parameters:
>
> key (bytes) – the cryptographic key
>
> mode – the constant `Crypto.Cipher.<algorithm>.MODE_GCM`
>
> nonce (bytes) – the value of the fixed nonce. It must be unique for the combination message/key. If not present, the library creates a random nonce (16 bytes long for AES).
>
> mac_len (integer) – the desired length of the MAC tag, from 4 to 16 bytes (default: 16).

I have a question regarding the `*` parameter, since this is not explained in the documentation, what is that symbol? and what is it for in the method?

Comment: Duplicate of [Star (\*) as an argument in python function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53797057/star-as-an-argument-in-python-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` here doesn't refer to a parameter itself - rather, it's a division between the parameters before it (which can be specified positionally or as keywords), and the parameters after it (which are keyword-only, and cannot be specified positionally).

[PEP 3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) goes into more detail.