# purpose of keyword value args in python?

Tags: python

```
def calculate_set(x,y, city, address, geo, etheraddress, email, country_of_origin):
   print(city)
   print(address)
   print(email)
   print(country_of_origin)
```

Suppose I pass the order of arguments in the wrong way:

```
calculate_set(30,40, geo = "rowanda", 
                 etheraddress= "xu203942", 
                 address="baker street 304", 
                 city="london", 
                 email = "abc@gmail.com", 
                 country_of_origin= 'uk')
```

The function will still work fine, whereas in java, it would just print error msg saying the order of args is wrong and it does not recognize it?
Is this the purpose of keyword args in python?

Comment: Lookup keyword arguments (kwargs) in Python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419046/normal-arguments-vs-keyword-arguments

Comment: @Iso also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters

Comment: Yes, you can use it like this if you want. However, it is usually used for default function arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to pass arguments to a function. Internally, arguments are passed by assignment. Function arguments are references to shared object referenced by the caller.

#### **Positional parameters**: matched left to right

> The normal case where arguments are passed by position.

```
func(a, b)  # Recieved as is left to right
```

#### **Keywords arguments**: matched by argument name

> Callers can specify which argument in the function is to receive a
>   value by using the argument’s name in the call.

```
func(a=10, b=20)  # Keyword argument or named argument -> POSITION DOESN'T MATTER
```

#### **variable args**: get unmatched positional or keyword arguments

> Functions can use special arguments to collect arbitrarily many extra
>   arguments (much as the varargs feature in C, Java which supports
>   variable-length argument lists).

```
func(**var_dict)  # Pass arguments as dictionary
```

#### **Defaults**: specify values for arguments that aren’t passed

> Functions may also specify default values for arguments to receive if
>   the call passes too few values

```
def func(a=10):
    print(a)

func()  # Prints 10
```

#### NOTE

***Positional parameters can't be passed after keyword arguments***

Comment: damn, this is some amazing answer!

Answer (score 1):

In Python only positional args (args w/o default values) require right order. Keyword arguments can be passed in any order, but should be passes only after positional args.