# In the common Odoo method 'execute_kw', what does the suffix 'kw' refer to?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-12

I can't for the life of me find any place where the suffix of the name of the common Odoo method `execute_kw` is explained. What is the `kw` suffix for?  Is it just two arbitrary letters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`KW` stands for keyword. Parameters are passed as keyword:value pairs making defined positional parameters unnecessary. See more info on Python keyword arguments at [Normal arguments vs. keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419046/normal-arguments-vs-keyword-arguments).