# How to modify local variable in a function in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to change the value of a parameter in an imported function without putting it as input. For instance:

```py
# in def_function.py
def test(x):
    parameter1 = 50 # default value
    return parameter1*x

# in main.py
from def_function import test
print(test(1)) # It should give me 50
parameter1 = 10 # changing the value of parameter1 in test function
print(test(1)) # It should give me 10
```

Comment: That's not going to work. `parameter1` in `main.py` is unrelated to `parameter1` inside the `test` function in `def_function.py`.

Comment: If you want to set a variable from outside you'll have to use a parameter as you did with `x`.

Comment: If you want a default value use `def test(x, parameter1=50)`. If you call the function without a second parameter it will use the default value of `50`.

Comment: If you want it to change, you'll have to pass it in somehow.  Either as a parameter, or a global.

Comment: Am I missing something but is there a reason you can't use a [default argument](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values)? `def test(x, parameter1=50)` and if you need a different `parameter1` just use `test(1, 10)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`parameter1` inside the function is in its own [**scope**](https://pythonspot.com/scope/). It's not the same as the `parameter1` outside the function definition.

To do what you're trying to do, add a [**keyword argument**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419046/normal-arguments-vs-keyword-arguments) to the function definition, providing a default value for the argument:

```
# in def_function.py
def test(x, parameter1=50):
    return parameter1*x

# in main.py
from def_function import test
print(test(1)) # It gives 50
print(test(1, parameter1=10)) # It gives 10 (as a keyword arg)
print(test(1, 10)) # It gives 10 (as a positional arg)
```

Don't use globals if you can help it.

Comment: Perfect ! That was the type of answer I was looking for. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the `nonlocal` keyword. You could do this in your code like this:

```
def main():
    def test(x):
        nonlocal parameter1
        return parameter1*x

    parameter1 = 50 # default value
    print(test(1)) # It should give me 50
    parameter1 = 10 # changing the value of parameter1 in test function
    print(test(1)) # It should give me 10
    
main()
```

Read more here:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_nonlocal.asp