# Getting an error while using opencv in jupyter notebook:

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter, image-morphology

Facing Syntax error while using this piece of code:

```
kernel_1 = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)

img_open = cv2.morphologyEx(img, op= cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel_1)
```

Error Message:

> img_open = cv2.morphologyEx(img, op= cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel_1)
>                                                          ^ SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Normal arguments vs. keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419046/normal-arguments-vs-keyword-arguments)

Comment: You have the arguments backwards. Try `kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))` and `opening = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

in `img_open = cv2.morphologyEx(img, op= cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel_1)`

`op= cv.MORPH_OPEN` is keyword argument and `img`, `kernel_1` is positional argument.

python not allow keyword argument before positional argument

try `cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel_1)`

Comment: Works perfect just removing `op=`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot follow a positional argument after a keyword argument.

```
func(my_argu=True)  # keyword argument i.e. position doesn't matter. it always goes to my_argu
func(my_argh_1, my_arg_2)  # positional argument i.e. position/order matters
```

So to fuix you function without looking at the documentation:

```py
cv.morphology(img, kernel_1, op=cv2.MORPH_OPEN)
or 
cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel_1)
```

Comment: Works perfectly just removing `op = `

Comment: Good. Be sure to mark as answered if that solves the question.

Answer (score -1):

The error is becuse you use the = statement for parameters before kernal_1

python will give an error if you do that an solution will be to try this:

```
kernel_1 = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)

img_open = cv2.morphologyEx(img, kernel_1,op=cv2.MORPH_OPEN)
```

i dont know if the locations of the parameters will be right but when it is this will solve your problem

and else you can also do this:

```
img_open = cv2.morphologyEx(img, op= cv2.MORPH_OPEN,{parameter_name}=kernel_1)
```

to solve this issue

Comment: This gives error:  `----> 3 img_open =cv2.morphologyEx(img, kernel_1,op=cv2.MORPH_OPEN)

TypeError: Argument given by name ('op') and position (2)`