# Passing argument with self assignment into constructor

Tags: python, porting

I am very new to Python. My objective is to convert a Python library to Java, which I have several years of experience with.

For the most part, porting this library has been a breeze with the exception of one single line of code (repeated several times) that I don't understand. I've tried searching for an answer to no avail. So here I am.

```
                                                             ↓                   ↓
self.push(ComparisonExpression(object_path, value, comparator=comparator, negated=negated))
```

In Java, this would be self-assignment. I don't imagine this being the same in Python because it achieves nothing. Is this a null check which results in a boolean? I am very confused.

Comment: They are keyword arguments. Java does not have such things; you'd have to use positional arguments.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419046/normal-arguments-vs-keyword-arguments

Comment: Keyword arguments have the form key=value. So in comparator=comparator, the first comparator is the keyword. The second is a reference to some variable in the scope of the call to self.push().

Comment: Thank you, folks. This is very helpful.