# How do I pass **kwargs when instantiating an object and access it in the class's __init__() method

Tags: python, django

Here I'd like to pass a `**kwargs` dictionary when instantiating my PlayerForm objects and be able to access it when calling `__init__()` method. This is what I've done below but it's not working.

This is somewhere in my views.py file:

```
context = {'player_form': PlayerForm(kwargs={'user': request.user})}
```

This is in my forms.py file

```
from .models import Game, Player

class PlayerForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Player
    fields = ['game', 'username']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    if kwargs.get('user'):
        self.fields['game'].queryset = Game.objects.exclude(player__user=user)
```

Comment: What is not working with it?  Are you getting an error? (post the error here). Are you getting an unexpected output? (Post the expected output and what you are getting here)

Comment: I've never seen someone actually use kwargs as a parameter when instantiating the object. Try `context = {'player_form': PlayerForm(user = request.user)}`

Comment: A function parameter like `**<var>` means "collect all remaining keyword arguments as a dictionary and store them in <var>"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Normal arguments vs. keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419046/normal-arguments-vs-keyword-arguments)

Comment: @user1558604 the solution worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use kwargs using ** operator.
Try using below code:

```
context = {'player_form': PlayerForm(**{'user': request.user})}
```

Comment: This is unnecessary and less readable than passing keyword arguments directly

Comment: You r right, but there might be the case where all the args would be in dictionary format. Ane question author wants it to work like this.