# Chop property in Jupyter

Tags: python, math, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I'm new to Jupyter and I found a property (or at least I think it is) in an example that says: chop = true.

Does anyone knows the use of this?

[image: Example]

Comment: This is Python code, it's a [keyword argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419046/normal-arguments-vs-keyword-arguments) of the method `evalf` that's been commented out and then uncommented. Unrelated to Jupyter.

Comment: please show us what library display is from. It should be on top of your notebook