# Error when calling dask scheduler story function

Tags: python, dask, slurm, dask-distributed

So I am following this example from dask documentation almost verbatim
https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/logging.html#task-transition-logs
and but could not get it to work. Below is my code:

```py
import dask
import time
import random
from dask_jobqueue import SLURMCluster
from distributed import Client

def dummy(x):
   time.sleep(5)
   return x

cluster = SLURMCluster(...) # you will need to put your queue name, cores, mem, etc...
client = Client(cluster)
f = client.submit(dummy, 2)
# we can sleep for a while for it to be finished

client.scheduler.story(f.key)
# client.scheduler.story(f) yields the same error
```

and I get this error:

`TypeError: send_recv_from_rpc() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given` on the line `client.scheduler.story(f.key)`.

Comment: It's unclear from your code where the `send_recv_from_rpc` method is called.

Comment: That is the error when `client.scheduler.story(f.key)` is called.

Comment: API of the `story` method takes only regular arguments, not positional ones.

Comment: can you clarify what is a "regular" argument in this case?
And I updated the issue description with the link to the dask documentation that i followed verbatim.

Comment: `f` variable is a Future so you need to implement the wait mechanism before you're calling the `story` method. Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

Comment: as I mentioned in the comments. I manually waited for the Future to be in a 'finished' state, and it will still have the same error.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1419159/5707560 about regular and positional arguments and check out the original code of the `story` method in the Scheduler class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244678/discussion-between-michaelgbj-and-yehor-smoliakov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, to access the scheduler use the `client.cluster.scheduler`, so the relevant code would look like this:

```py
print(client.cluster.scheduler.story(f.key))
# print the story
```